# zsh-syntax-highlighting for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, zsh, syntax-highlighting

I've been using Zsh for a long time and have installed a syntax highlighting extension such that, as shown in the picture below, when I enter the name of a program that doesn't exist on the console, the text will automatically turn red.

[image]

However, I also have a Windows PC and am currently wondering how I could install such an extension or how I could configure my PowerShell to work the same way. I know it's possible because, as you can see on the .gif image below, the color of the text automatically changed when I typed in different types of variables on my current PowerShell.

[image]

Comment: have you tried searching for `powershell zsh` yet?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, of course, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the [pwsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/digitalguy99/pwsh-syntax-highlighting) module. It is very similar to the syntax-highlighting extension on `zsh` with the exception that it is still in development and only validates the first word entered into the prompt.